# Method not found - While hosting in IIS

Tags: c#, angularjs, iis

I have an application (API and the web app runs on the same port number). Which works perfectly when I host it in my iis. But when I do the same on the client machine it says

"POST XHR
http://localhost:12345/api/Login/InsertUser [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]".

When I open the url "http://localhost:12345/api/Login/InsertUser" in my local machine it opens without any errors. But if i do the same on the client machine it throws an error that the method name is changed or not found.

I have done the web app using angular js and API is written in C# and Back End using SQL Server.

Do I need to enable any thing on IIS . I tried adding the MIME Type Json in the IIS. Still it did not work. Can anyone help me out with this issue. Thanks

Comment: On your local machine it is localhost, but on the client's one it is not localhost anymore. Use the IP address.

Comment: I am getting this error even after changing the localhost to IP address        " HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."